# Replace dangerous char avoid xss?

Tags: asp.net, xss

I have developed a blog site.Users can publish their blogs.

Users can input code like javascript,c#,java and html tags like strong tag etc...

I order to avoid xss,I would like to replace all dangerous chars like below,But this security?

```
WebForm1.aspx.cs:

 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string V;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            V = HtmlEncode("Get content from DB");

        }
        public string HtmlEncode(string theString)
        {
            theString = theString.Replace(">", "&gt;");
            theString = theString.Replace("<", "&lt;");
            theString = theString.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
            theString = theString.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
            theString = theString.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
            theString = theString.Replace("\'", "'");
            theString = theString.Replace("\n", "<br/> ");
            ..................
            ..................
            ...................
            return theString;
        }
    }
```

WebForm1.aspx:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%=V%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not simple use .NET HtmlEncode function?

Comment: Users can input code like javascript,c#,java and html tags like <strong> etc

Comment: Yes and Server.HtmlEncode function will encode them. Why invent the wheel?

Comment: Please try  Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode("<strong>test</strong>")); On the aspx page the text test not bold。

Comment: It won't be bold using your function either, you replacing angle brackets

Comment: TKS.you are right.I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to let user enter so called "bb-code".

Still use `Server.HtmlEncode` to prevent user from entering any *real* tags, but allow to enter substitutions.

For example if user enters:

```
 [b]test[/b]
```

in your server-side code you replace it with

```
 <strong>test</strong>
```

Same goes for italic, other styles and colors. This way you control subset of allowed HTML. Using BB-code is a standard practice on forums and blogs.